# How to find $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-(1-2^{-k})^n) }{\ln n}$

Tags: limits, summation, logarithms

How  to find $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-(1-2^{-k})^n) }{\ln n}.$$
Is there a simple way?